# Update existing Installation

Tags: install4j

I am trying to create an installer which will work as an installer in normal cases and if application is already installed it will update the existing installation.

I created an add-on installer with the new files. It works fine when executed independently.

To integrate it with the original installer, i merged this add-on installer with main installer .Then i checked if the app is already installed and added the "Add link to.." add-on installer.

But this installs all the files of the "Add on " as well as the main installer. Is this expected? As i am not even executing "Install Files" action of main installer. It installs the unnecessary files of original installer.

Is there any way to just execute the "Install files" action of only "Add-On" installer?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create an installer which will work as an installer in normal cases and if
> application is already installed it will update the existing installation.

Do not use an "Add-on installer" for that purpose. This is exactly what the regular installer does.

Comment: So ,you mean just execute the installer again on installed directory and it will update it? Then it will also execute all the actions (eg. service install, some other software installation) which is not what i want. I just want to replace some files.

Comment: You can guard actions and screens and groups of them with the condition expression `!context.isUpdateInstallation()`. You can also make another installer with the same application ID if that suits you better, but it must be a regular installer, not an add-on installer.

Comment: Ok. I agree that actions can be controlled as you said. But "Install Files" will install (copy) all the files in distribution tree. This will copy unnecessary files which is what i am trying to avoid.

Comment: The "Install Files" action has a "File filter" property for that purpose.

Comment: Ok. So we need to maintain the array of file names and check in File filter.

Comment: Also can we the uninstall just the update? or it will get completely uninstalled?

Comment: There is no functionality to rollback the effects of an update installer later on, the uninstaller will uninstall the entire installation.